# Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать сервер мультиплеерной игры камень-ножницы-бумага на go с горутинами

Tags: golang

Собственно сабж.
Условия (кратко):

1. Сервер принимает запросы от многих клиентов постоянно на один и тот же адрес методом Get переменной `val` с возможными параметрами "join", "rock", "papper" или "scissors", переменной `player` c ником игрока и переменной `from` с адресом:портом клиента для ответа сервера.
2. Если клиент не в поединке, то отправив "join" он может присоединиться к поединку (в комнату ожидания). Если кроме него другой клиент находится в ожидании, то наступает матч. Если кроме него других клиентов в ожидании нет, то он ждет присоединения другого игрока.
3. Если победитель выявлен, то матч завершается и оба могут присоединиться заново. Если победитель не выявлен, то матч рестартуется до выявления победителя.
4. **Необходимо реализовать задачу при помощи горутин.**
5. Использование сторонних библиотек запрещено. Использование драйвера для работы с бд разрешено.

Без горутин я реализовал задачу примитивно с сохранением параметров в базу и кучи условий if... Then... Но нужно именно с использованием горутин, а моих знаний в параллелизме недостаточно.

Как я это предполагаю:

1. При получении первой команды "join" запускается горутина комнаты которая ждет 2 канала. В один из каналов передается первый игрок
2. При получении второй команды "join" в канал передается второй игрок и начинается матч запуском бесконечного цикла, выход из которого только при наличии победителя.
3. Цикл в горутине должен принимать команды из горутины main и отправлять результат игрокам.

...

Пока писал, запутался окончательно...
Прошу помощи в поиске информационных материалов по этой или подобной задаче. Будет здорово если найутся ссылки на видео или подробную статью (на инглише тоже сойдет). Буду сильно рад подробному ответу, если таковой будет. Мозг кипит от попыток понять тему и простить моего преподавателя ибо тема параллелизма в моем обучении Golang осталась не раскрыта.

Заранее спасибо за реакцию.